# Reopen same Colorbox with different Query string

Tags: javascript, dom, colorbox

I have to load same html page with in colorbox but with different Query string parameters. Everything is working fine except JQuery. i.e. the count of some specific divs, I am using $('div').length;  and it is returning the wrong output which is the sum of last opened colorbox and currently opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to be more specific when your asking for help in Q/A site. Even if your English is not perfect more information about the problem your facing will help us help you. I'm going to try my best to make sense of what your asking :

> I have to load same html page that uses a colorbox but with different
>   Query string parameters.

What color box library, tool or script are you using?

> Everything is working fine except JQuery.

I assume your having a problem with a jQuery command.

> The count of some specific divs, I am using $('div').length; and it is
>   returning the wrong output

What is the expected output?

> which is the sum of last opened colorbox
>   and currently opened.

I'm not sure what you meant by that statement.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it is a [Q & A site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). All of the stuff in this answer probably should have been addressed with comments on the question, not an answer.

Comment: I tried answering with a comment but comments have character limits and there where too many things that needed to be improved in this question.